# Is there a way to stop the back button disappearing when using a UINavigationController in an Xcode playground?

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, swift-playground

please run the following gist in Xcode to verify the behaviour and suggest a workaround. cheers.

[playground demonstrating disappearing back button](https://gist.github.com/DanielAsher/8112d5215074e554e959f2212fc03190)